# jupyter nbconvert cannot work with latest version of pandoc

Tags: jupyter, pandoc, nbconvert

I got this error when converting a ipynb file to latex.  Looks like there's a [hardcoded upper bound](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/blob/2dd65d2599a49cb5dd4bee4f86b8deaa26bfa86a/nbconvert/utils/pandoc.py#L17-L18) on pandoc in nbconvert.  Is there any reason why it would work with the latest version?

nbconvert/utils/pandoc.py:52: RuntimeWarning: You are using an unsupported version of pandoc (2.2.1). Your version must be at least (1.12.1) but less than (2.0.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many command line options have changed between pandoc v1.* and pandoc v2, e.g. `--smart` is no longer recognized as pandoc uses a finer-grained mechanism now. In general, it seems like a good idea to limit the acceptable version.

That being said, nbconvert seems to only use options which have *not* changed; it is probably save to bump the upper version bound.